# Possible bug with materialsteppers

Tags: java, android

It sounds there is a bug with this library: https://github.com/shivasurya/materialsteppers

The bug is the following: if we are in step 2, for example, and we click next, the oncreate of step 4 is called instead of oncreate of step 3. When we click next, neither the oncreate nor oncreateview of next fragment is called. Which method of the next fragment is called?

Does somebody faced the same problem?

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ProgressMobileStepper {

List<Class> stepperFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public List<Class> init() {

    stepperFragmentList.add(Step1Fragment.class);
    stepperFragmentList.add(Step2Fragment.class);
    stepperFragmentList.add(Step3Fragment.class);
    stepperFragmentList.add(Step4Fragment.class);
    stepperFragmentList.add(Step5Fragment.class);

    return stepperFragmentList;
}

}
```

Fragment 1:

```
public class Step1Fragment extends StepperFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {

    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return view;
}
}
```

Fragment 2

```
public class Step2Fragment extends StepperFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {

    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return view;
}
}
```

Fragment 3:

```
public class Step3Fragment extends StepperFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {

    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return view;
}
}
```

Fragment 4:

```
public class Step4Fragment extends StepperFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {

    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return view;
}
}
```

Fragment 5:

```
public class Step5Fragment extends StepperFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {

    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return view;
}
}
```